# Cannot read unrecognized property CRM_Core_Config::$mapGeoCoding

Tags: civievent, geocoding, google

Has anyone encountered this error on a CiviCRM Event:

Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. Cannot read unrecognized property CRM_Core_Config::$mapGeoCoding

I'm using civi version 4.7.13. I changed the Mapping and Geocoding Providers Settings. Google is the Geocoding Provider and I added a Geo Provider Key. When I save the settings the error disappears but the map does not display on the page and eventually the error returns

Comment: I'm not totally sure but there are changes in that code since that version that may have fixed the problem (or at least will have changed it!)

Comment: I have upgraded to 5.3.1 and I also get the above error. I got this after upgrading from 4 to 5.3.1 in steps like 4.x to 5.0 and 5.0 to 5.3.1

Comment: Hi Rene , did you find a solution to the above?

Answer (score -1):

Removing $config->mapGeoCoding from the core EventInfo.tpl and then clearing the directories out of the */templates_c/En_us directory fixed the error message. I am now able to get the map to work correctly if I enter the longitude/latitude but I think there is an issue with the key.